# sort post in custom post type by multiple custom fields acf

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 4 text field type in a custom post type, these are `brand_fbn`,`model_fbn`,`year_fbn` and `plate_number`. I want to sort the post, by `brand_fbn` - `model_fbn` - `year_fbn` - `plate_number`. But im stuck with that,

this is my code(error)

```
                        $ins = new WP_Query(array(
                            "post_type" =>      "application-list",
                            "author"    =>      $current_user->ID,
                            "meta_key"      =>  array("year_fbn","plate_number"),
                            "orderby"       =>  "meta_value ",
                            "order"         =>  "ASC"
                        ));
```

I know this line wont work, `"meta_key"=>array("year_fbn","plate_number"),` can someone help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to query for the meta fields so that they are `JOIN`ed within `WP_Query` and then use the `posts_orderby` filter to order your results by those meta fields - the alias use will be in the format `mt1.meta_value`.

```
// Function to replace the order by clause in the SQL generated by WP_Query
function custom_order_by( $order_by ){
    return str_replace( 
        'menu_order', 
        'mt1.meta_value, mt2.meta_value, mt3.meta_value, mt4.meta_value',
        $order_by 
    );
}

// args for WP_Query
$args = array(
    "post_type"   => "application-list",
    "author"      => $current_user->ID,
    "meta_query"  => array(
        array( 
            "key"     => "brand_fbn", 
            "compare" => "LIKE",
            "value"   => ""
        ),
        array( 
            "key"     => "model_fbn", 
            "compare" => "LIKE",
            "value"   => ""
        ),
        array( 
            "key"     => "year_fbn", 
            "compare" => "LIKE",
            "value"   => ""
        ),
        array( 
            "key"     => "plate_number", 
            "compare" => "LIKE",
            "value"   => ""
        )
    )
);

// add filter to modify order by clause
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'custom_order_by' );
// run the WP_Query
$ins = new WP_Query( $args );
// remove the filter so that other queries aren't affected.
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'custom_order_by' );
```